# Expired Database Password and Still-Alive Connections

Tags: database, oracle, jdbc, database-connection

I open a few oracle connections with oracle jdbc. And I need to test a certain case where the db's password gets expired and the connections should be not working. However, when I manually expire the db password, the connections still stay open and working. What should I do for connections to get closed or to get closed when I expire the db password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a user password expiration occurs *in the middle* of an already established connection(session), it will not end a user session - the session wont be automatically closed. The user will be able to proceed and prompted(SQL*PLUS or other tools) to change  his/her password on the first attempt to log in after the expiration. That the right behavior. Let a user finish what he/she has already started. If you able to close a connection killing a user session right after the expiration you probably wont do it clean and user's work cold be lost.

---

**Edit**

> In case the user doesn't log in again, when would the connections get closed? Is there  a stay-alive time for connections or something like that?

First of all let's define session and connection. Session is a logical entity and connection is a physical one. And one connection can have from 0 to n sessions established on it(You can test it using sql*plus CLI and information from `v$process` view). Thus password expiration leans more toward user session than connection and when a user logs out, its session ceases to exist, but connection can still be established and closed when a client application is closed.

> would a session stay open forever until the user logs out?

Yes, it's possible. if you are absolutely sure that a user or an application has got their work done and simply forgot to close a session, you can use `alter system kill session <<SID>>, <<Serial_Number>>` to kill(you have to be granted `alter system privilege`) the session(s).

> Are there any time constraints?

You could create a [profile](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6010.htm) with `IDLE_TIME` option specified.

```
create profile <<Profile_name>> limit idle_time <<num_of_minutes>>
```

and assign it to a user. When a session inactivity time - time when a session is not making any SQL calls exceeds `<<num_of_minutes>>` Oracle will rolls back the current transaction and end that session.

You also can configure terminating of a connection that is no longer in use by setting `SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME` [parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/network.101/b10776/sqlnet.htm), in minutes, in the `sqlnet.ora` file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In case the user doesn't log in again, when would the connections get closed? Is there a stay-alive time for connections or something like that?

Comment: Given your definitions, would a session stay open forever until the user logs out? And what closes a connection except I tell the application to close? Are there any time constraints?